# How to show polynomial tread line in Am-Line chart

Tags: amcharts

How can i show a polynomial tread line in Am-line chart. I'm getting a straight trend line here, i need a polynomial trend line. My javascript code is shown below. Please someone help me to solve this issue.

```
function GenChartData() {
    var data1 = [0.234761158, 0.23816127, 0.263960124, 0.282558558, 0.300607979, 0.318197719, 0.316059534, 0.319133276, 0.322505238, 0.323926338, 0.323720379, 0.3203703, 0.318837626, 0.318380371, 0.321465339, 0.316398839, 0.310238176, 0.301206892, 0.278454166, 0.268778255, 0.250299958, 0.23754735, 0.216277621, 0.182483871, 0.152057602, 0.129372542, 0.079524595, 0.044074801, 0.007279248, -0.021369877, -0.022801251, -0.043247196, -0.060677351, -0.055932729, -0.055847788, -0.032625365, -0.027289726, -0.022615401, -0.010850169, 0.015833104, 0.043923065, 0.055500831, 0.048043121, 0.054154849, 0.064038257, 0.049914887, 0.046542406, 0.03154397, 0.033614909, 0.030570225, 0.035606699, 0.001179461, -0.028934007, -0.019034206, 2.30344E-05];
    var dates = ["12/31/2001", "1/31/2002", "2/28/2002", "3/31/2002", "4/30/2002", "5/31/2002", "6/30/2002", "7/31/2002", "8/31/2002", "9/30/2002", "10/31/2002", "11/30/2002", "12/31/2002", "1/31/2003", "2/28/2003", "3/31/2003", "4/30/2003", "5/31/2003", "6/30/2003", "7/31/2003", "8/31/2003", "9/30/2003", "10/31/2003", "11/30/2003", "12/31/2003", "1/31/2004", "2/29/2004", "3/31/2004", "4/30/2004", "5/31/2004", "6/30/2004", "7/31/2004", "8/31/2004", "9/30/2004", "10/31/2004", "11/30/2004", "12/31/2004", "1/31/2005", "2/28/2005", "3/31/2005", "4/30/2005", "5/31/2005", "6/30/2005", "7/31/2005", "8/31/2005", "9/30/2005", "10/31/2005", "11/30/2005", "12/31/2005", "1/31/2006", "2/28/2006", "3/31/2006", "4/30/2006", "5/31/2006", "6/30/2006"];

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    chartData.push({
    date: new Date(dates[i]),
    data1: data1[i]});
}
}
AmCharts.ready(function () {
// SERIAL CHART
GenChartData();
chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
chart.pathToImages = "JS/AmFiles/amcharts/images/";
chart.marginTop = 0;
chart.marginRight = 10;
chart.autoMarginOffset = 5;
//chart.backgroundColor = "#CCCCC";
chart.zoomOutButton = {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    backgroundAlpha: 0.15
};
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.categoryField = "date";

// listen for "dataUpdated" event (fired when chart is rendered) and call zoomChart method when it happens
chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

// AXES
// category
var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
categoryAxis.minPeriod = "MM"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
categoryAxis.dashLength = 1;
categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.15;
categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
categoryAxis.labelFrequency = 1;
categoryAxis.equalSpacing = true;

// value
var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.2;
valueAxis.dashLength = 1;
chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.type = "smoothedLine";
graph.lineColor = "#180ad1";
graph.negativeLineColor = "#180ad1";
graph.bullet = "round";
graph.bulletSize = 5;
graph.lineThickness = 2;
graph.valueField = "data1";
chart.addGraph(graph);

// CURSOR
chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

// TREND LINES
// first trend line
var trendLine = new AmCharts.TrendLine();
trendLine.initialDate = new Date(chartData[0].date); // 12 is hour - to start trend line in the middle of the day
trendLine.finalDate = new Date(chartData[chartData.length-1].date);
trendLine.initialValue = 0.234761158;
trendLine.finalValue = 2.30344E-05;
trendLine.lineColor = "#CC0000";
chart.addTrendLine(trendLine);

// WRITE
chart.write("chartdiv");
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You would need to basically have another graphline on there rather than a trendline.

You can look at this example - http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/line-with-different-bullet-sizes/

to see how to equip multiple data graphs.

Comment: Why links are useful try to explain more of their content in your answers in case the link dies.